# how to call a function instide an php array as a value

Tags: php

I am trying to call a function inside an array as a value but is not working the function instead is echoed outside the array.

Here is my code example:

```
function plm() {
    global $InfoPing;
    foreach($InfoPing['description']['extra'] as $plm) {
        echo $plm['text'];
    }
}

$json = array(
    'status' => 'Online',
    'motd' => array(
        'ingame' => plm()
    ),
    'host' => array(
        'host' => $host,
        'port' => $port
    ),
    'players' => array(
        'max' => $InfoPing['players']['max'],
        'online' => $InfoPing['players']['online']
    ),
    'version' => array(
        'version' => $version[1],
        'protocol' => $InfoPing['version']['protocol']
    ),
    'queryinfo' => array(
        'agreement' => 'Ping',
        'processed' => $Timer
    )
);

echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[image: here are the results]
Any help highly is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Blake Ottinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2224559/blake-ottinger) points out in their answer, you need to `return` the data, not `echo`.  But when you `return`, you exit the function and only the first value will be returned.  If you want `text` from all elements of `$InfoPing['description']['extra']`, then build an array and return it:

```
function plm() {
    global $InfoPing;
    foreach($InfoPing['description']['extra'] as $plm) {
        $result[] = $plm['text'];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

However, instead of the function you can just extract all `text` with a built-in function and assign it to the array:

```
'ingame' => array_column($InfoPing['description']['extra'], 'text');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue stems from your usage of `echo` within the `plm()` function. Because it echoes instead of returning, it sends it to the browser ahead of the rest of the JSON, and then returns `NULL`, thereby inserting the `NULL` value into the array. Change it to `return` instead.

```php
function plm() {
    global $InfoPing;
    foreach($InfoPing['description']['extra'] as $plm) {
        return $plm['text'];
    }
}
```

This should fix your issues.

Comment: I would question why they use a loop as `return` returns only the first one.